# Does any pseudo-Riemannian metric admit a metric-compatible linear connection with vanishing curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It is well-known that a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ admits a (unique) torsion-free linear connection $\stackrel{\circ}{\nabla}$ that is compatible with the given metric, i.e. $\stackrel{\circ}{\nabla} g = 0$.

Is it true that there also exists a curvature-free metric-compatible connection $\nabla$? Or under what circumstances?

---

**Edit:**

About my conjecture below:

*In the refined case of a parallelizable pseudo-Riemannian manifold, does there always exist a curvature-free metric-compatible linear connection?*

Take as an counterexample the **maximally-extended Schwarzschild spacetime** $(M,g)$. It is parallelizable as the underlying manifold is homeomorphic to $S^2 \times \mathbb R^2$. Suppose there exists a metric-compatible curvature-free connection $\nabla$. Since $M$ is simply-connected, the holonomy group $\operatorname{Hol}^{\nabla}(p)$ vanishes for any point $p \in M$. We thus can construct a global orthonormal frame using the parallel transport of $\nabla$. However, no such global orthonormal frame exists. A contradiction.

Comment: This will is not possible for the sphere with the standard euclidean inner product, because the tangent bundle has nonvanishing euler class (not sure how much that helps you).

Comment: Let me see if what I will claim now holds true:
If there exists a flat linear connection on a vector bundle (not necessarily metric-compatible), then the vector bundle is trivial?
Hence, the manifold in question has to meet the topological requirement of being parallelizable in order to admit a flat linear connection at all?

Comment: The Möbius bundle has a flat linear connection. It isn't the tangent space to a manifold though.

Comment: So my claim above is wrong. (In order to refine, does it at least hold that a vector bundle over a simply-connected base that admits a flat linear connection is trivial?)
Anyway, so I resume that there is some necessary topological requirement for the existence of a flat metric-compatible connection on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold.
This condition seems to be weaker than the requirement of a parallelizable manifold(?)
In the refined case of a parallelizable pseudo-Riemannian manifold, does there always exist a flat metric-compatible linear connection?